# A confusing question about relative clauses!

Tags: grammar

Why in the following statement should we use "what is now"?

Why not "which is now", "where now is", "that is now", etc?

The first person executed in **what is now** the United States was Captain George Kendall, a councilor for the Virginia Colony.

Comment: 'What is now' is used in examples like this to replace 'the situation / condition / thing / place ... now existing / obtaining [in contrast to the previous situation / ...]'. Think of 'what' as replacing 'the place [previously consisting of ...] that is now known as'.

Comment: No, you can't use "which" or "that". It's not a relative clause, but a noun phrase. It's called a 'fused' relative construction because the antecedent and the head noun are combined or 'fused' into the single word "what" instead of being expressed separately.  It's the equivalent of the non-fused "The first person executed in the country which is now the United States ...", where you can clearly see the head and antecedent